What does it mean when it says a Spam report message might be sent to carrier
I accidentally reported a conversation that I did not mean to report spam, and my carrier is someone I don't want to see these messages.

What does it mean when it says it might get sent to the carrier?
I've already deleted the spam report, but does that mean my carrier still has a report about it?
Who do I contact to ask these questions?


Which app are you talking about "Messages" (SMS/RCS) app or some third party messaging app like Whatsapp?

Possibly related/dupe (not answered yet): When "might" reported spam be sent to my carrier [...]?

Im referring to Messages @Robert

The Google support link titled "Report spam in Google Messages" seems pretty clear:

Your report might create a separate “Spam reporting” conversation. This will send a copy of the spammer’s number plus the most recent text message to your mobile carrier. These conversations may be spam and blocked automatically.

I report spams via Google Messages regularly, and it never creates another SMS conversation for me incurring additional SMS charges. This commercial blog "How to report spam texts" says it is conditional on the carrier, but even North American carriers have their own reporting mechanisms.
If it doesn't affect your life legally, not having a separate conversation created based on your report seems pretty good.  Otherwise, it seems pretty hard to get a definite answer, looking at @andrew-t 's link.
